# what does *otherwise* mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *otherwise* mean in this sentence?

> You do not need to be living on one of the southern European contries
>   to understand the implications of ***otherwise*** well-intentioned job
>   protection, and why it is better to protect workers than to protect
>   jobs.

There are some definition for it in dictionary but I do not understand its meaning here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word **otherwise** there alludes to  unintended side-effects and undesirable consequences of such job-protection measures, the "implications".  The measures, though they have had those side-effects, were *in all other respects* well-intentioned.

The sentence is a bit elliptical. The word **otherwise** is perhaps not the best way to contrast the intention of the measures with their unforeseen consequences.

> You do not need to be living in one of the southern European countries
>   to understand the adverse implications of even the most well-intentioned job
>   protection measures, and why it is better to protect workers than to
>   protect jobs.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding a real sentence with "otherwise well-intentioned" used properly - it seems to be a common mistake. Here's one I think is OK "...civil liberties advocates worry that conversations of innocent citizens can be incidentally swept up during *otherwise well-intentioned* surveillance." [VOA news](https://www.voanews.com/a/sorting-out-united-states-surveillance-methods-laws/3807708.html)